# Firestore rules map for object

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a collection. Each document have an object readers which will store the uid of people who will have access to the documents. It could be one or many user that can access to a document
[image]

I'm using angular firebase

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      this.users = afs.collection<User>('users', ref => ref.where('readers.' + auth.uid, '==', true)).valueChanges();
    });
  }
```

If I user the rule allow all read, my page will show the correct entries

```
match /users/{userId=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
```

If I add in the rule to filter using uid I get the error Missing or insufficient permissions.

```
match /users/{userId=**} {
      allow read, write: if resource.data.readers[request.auth.uid] == true ||
                        resource.readers[request.auth.uid] == true;
    }
```

Appreciate any help on what did I do wrong for the rules.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to put a `.` inside `if resource.data.readers.[request.auth.uid] == true` like this

Comment: That would be a syntax error.

Comment: ok in the docs they used `$(request.auth.uid)` to get the value. try `if resource.data.readers[$(request.auth.uid)] == true`

Comment: `resource.data.readers[$(request.auth.uid)]` returns syntax error Combing through the docs I saw that it should be `resource.data.readers[(request.auth.uid)]`. Tried that and it didn't work as well.
`if resource.data.readers[(request.auth.uid)] == true` and
`if resource.data.readers[(request.auth.uid)] != null`

Comment: Looks like `resource.readers[request.auth.uid] == true` is working now

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried changing your rules on database-rules to auth=null?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work as a collection will have multiple document where each document will be access by different users.